# Why does e.currentTarget change with jQuery's event delegation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

http://jsbin.com/xaguxuhiwu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

```
  <div id="container">
    <button id="foo">Foo button</button>
    <button id="bar">Bar button</button>
  </div>

$('#container').on('click', function(e) {
  var targetId = e.target.getAttribute('id');
  // Manually do event delegation
  if (targetId === 'foo') {
    var currentId = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('id');
    console.log('without delegation, currentTarget is: ' + currentId);
  }
});

$('#container').on('click', '#foo', function(e) {
    var currentId = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('id');
    console.log('with delegation, currentTarget is: ' + currentId);
});
```

Basically, my understanding of e.currentTarget for an event is that it reflects the point to which the event has bubbled to. Since I have an event listener on the `#container` element, I would expect the currentTarget to be `container` in both scenarios.

This is true for the standard `on` handler, as shown by the first example. However, when using event delegation (the `#foo` argument on the second click), currentTarget changes to be the inner button.

Why does the `e.currentTarget` change between the two scenarios?
 Specifically, in the latter case, does this mean that jQuery is not putting the event listener on the parent (`#container`) element?

Comment: In the second function, you're sorta telling jquery "Fire event when I click on an element with id="foo" that is nested somewhere in the element with id="container". Also, since you're pre-loading your html elements, and not inserting after the DOM loads, you don't need `.on` technically, and in the second function you can access element `#foo` without having to reference element `#container` first.

Comment: Also, instead of using `e.currentTarget` you can use `this`. With vanilla JS you can change `e.currentTarget.getAttribute('id')` to `this.id` and to `$(this).attr('id')` in jQuery.

Comment: @AaronEveleth: That is not my understanding of `.on` in jQuery. `.on()` should add a listener to any elements in the preceding selector.

When you add a second parameter (aka to use event delegation), my understanding is that jQuery will not invoke the callback function unless the `event.target` matches the selector.

Comment: With respect to `this`, my question is specifically about `currentTarget`. That property has specific semantics in the DOM. Either jQuery is modifying the currentTarget for some unknown reason, or the event handler is actually being bound differently than expected.

Comment: From my understanding, when you pass a second selector, it becomes the new event.CurrentTarget, relying on the first selector to have existed on initial DOM load if it was inserted after DOM load.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically it's because of jQuery magic behind the scenes. The jQuery event object that wraps the native event is changing the `currentTarget`, to be what might be more-convenient.

To access the value normally pointed to by `currentTarget`, jQuery events have [`delegateTarget`](https://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/).

> This property is most often useful in delegated events attached by `.delegate()` or `.on()`, where the event handler is attached at an ancestor of the element being processed. It can be used, for example, to identify and remove event handlers at the delegation point.
>
> For non-delegated event handlers attached directly to an element, `event.delegateTarget` will always be equal to `event.currentTarget`.

You can see that in the `originalEvent`, `currentTarget` has the value you would expect.

```js
$('#container').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('without delegation:');
    console.log('target: ' + e.target.getAttribute('id'));
    console.log('currentTarget: ' + e.currentTarget.getAttribute('id'));
    console.log('originalEvent.currentTarget: ' + e.originalEvent.currentTarget.getAttribute('id'));
    console.log('delegateTarget: ' + e.delegateTarget.getAttribute('id'));
    console.log('--');
});
$('#container').on('click', '#foo', function(e) {
    console.log('with delegation:');
    console.log('target: ' + e.target.getAttribute('id'));
    console.log('currentTarget: ' + e.currentTarget.getAttribute('id'));
    console.log('originalEvent.currentTarget: ' + e.originalEvent.currentTarget.getAttribute('id'));
    console.log('delegateTarget: ' + e.delegateTarget.getAttribute('id'));
    console.log('--');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <button id="foo">Foo button</button>
    <button id="bar">Bar button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're a nerd like me and want to see where jQuery is doing this [the source code is within the `dispatch` section of event.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L324).

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I wonder why this was done by the framework though? Wouldn't this always make it such that `e.target` === `e.currentTarget`?

Comment: Oh I rubber ducked my own solution. Suppose you have a hierarchy of three divs: grandparent, parent, and child. If you `$('#grandparent').on('click', '#parent', ...)`, then e.target should be the child, e.currentTarget (the jquery one) would be the parent.

Comment: @AnilRedshift Just a guess, but I suspect they may be trying to preserve some of the behavior from the obsolete `.live` method, which I believe used a different event binding strategy. I'm not sure though.

Comment: Yay appcompat!!

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, the "#foo" is the current DOM element, as that is what you clicked on. It is simply a DOM element who's parent (or parent's parent, etc) happens to be "#container".

The answer to your question therefore is "**The *current* DOM element within the event bubbling phase**." [as per jQuery docs) is "#foo".

Likewise if you called `$(document).on("click","#foo",...` your currentTarget would also be "#foo".